# Can the name of our site in SEDE be updated?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Some time ago the name of *Writers*.SE was changed to *Writing*.SE as can be seen in the post [This site is now Writing](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/this-site-is-now-writing). Today I noticed that the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) still uses "Writers".

The short network pitch is old, too. It says:

> Q&A for authors, editors, reviewers, professional writers, and aspiring writers

It should say:

> Q&A for the craft of professional writing, including fiction, non-fiction, technical, scholarly, and commercial writing.

Can this be updated?

Comment: I pointed out this question to the maintainer of SEDE.  SEDE is a volunteer project, not an official part of SE, so I don't know when this might get some attention.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I wasn't aware that it's a volunteer project. Thank you!

Comment: It's a very *handy* volunteer project.  I'm glad we have it.

Comment: "Moderators" changed its name to "Community Building" about two years ago and is still "Moderators" in SEDE.  Don't hold your breath.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, this was [fixed as of early 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306338/323179):

[image: Q&A for the craft of professional writing, including fiction, non-fiction, technical, scholarly, and commercial writing.]